# StringUtils for ant build files?

Tags: string, ant

I am looking for some util methods for strings manipulation. Eg. split a version into its major.minor.bugfix parts:

```
1.0.2

major=1
minor=0
bugfix=2
```

I have looked at:

http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/tools/ant/util/StringUtils.html

which is located in my C:\apache-ant-1.8.2\lib\ant.jar

but how do I use eg. the plit method in my build.xml file?

Here its done using groovy:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/431213/tools/Ant-Split-string-assign-property

But is there no "official" ant jar/extensions that contain this basic kind of string manipulation tasks that can be called in my build.xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [**Ant Addon Flaka**](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/), it provides some functions for string manipulation,
[**some examples here**](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/wiki/FlakaExamples).
The answer to your problem is the example :
Question : Given is an ant property which has value of the type 1.0.0.123
How to extract the value after the last dot, in this case that would be '123' ?
Solution : use the split function with index 
Alternatively use [**Groovy's Ant tas**](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task)k or script task with groovy/jruby/beanshell..